# Using Silverlight 4 with MVVM, how can I to scroll to the top of a page programatically

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, scroll

I have a Silverlight Application that navigates between pages.  Somehow the browser seems to remember the last scrolled location of a page, so that when I return to the page, I return to the same location.

For example:
Page 1 has a search list
Page 2 has details with a link at the bottom of the page back to the search list

If Page 2 exceeds the height of the browser, causing vertical scroll bars, when I select a send item from the list on page 1, I'm served up page 2 properly, but scrolled to the bottom of the page where the link was.

How can I get the browser page to navigate back to the top of the page?
Is there a MVVM solution, rather than a javascript solution in the XAML page?are times when I want to location not to change

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ScrollViewer wraps two ScrollBar controls for Vertical and Horizontal ScrollBars. The vertical scrollbar has a "Value" property that has a TemplateBinding to VerticalOffset, which i believe is what sets the location. which is a property of the Scrollviewer. Unfortunately, this is not a Dependency property, so you can't bind to it directly in your VM. The ScrollViewer does have a method named ScrollToVerticalOffset, and there you can specify the location. If you really want the logic in your VM, you could attempt to write a custom Template for ScrollViewer and bind the Value property in your ScrollBar to your Vm.

Comment: This probably isn't the best place to put this, but I can't seem to comment on your answer. Where's the ScrollToTop() method coming from? I don't see it in the msdn documentation, and I can't seem to find it in my ScrollViewers either.

Comment: Silverlight 4.3 controls http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.scrollviewer.scrolltoverticaloffset%28v=vs.95%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to do this, with a 3 part solution:

1) in the main page xaml add a Loaded Event

```
<ScrollViewer  ...  Loaded="ScrollViewer_Loaded">
```

2) in the code behind page xaml.cs store the reference in a global variable

```
private void ScrollViewer_Loaded(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e) 
{     gContentScroll = (ScrollViewer)sender;     }
```

3) anywhere else, you can access this global as needed, for example, in SomeOtherViewModel.cs

During the OnLoad initializations

```
...
gContentScroll.ScrollToVerticalOffset(0);
...
```